# How to convert string to date BigQuery 2023-02-13 00:00:00.000000000

Tags: string, date, datetime, google-bigquery, string-to-datetime

Help me please! I have date to string fotmat in
2023-02-13 00:00:00.00000000
Any conversion ends with an error. tried a lot of ways. Has anyone experienced something similar?

I try this
`PARSE_DATETIME('%m/%d/%Y',date)  PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y',date) PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S%Ez"`

and many more tries...
Failed to parse input string "2023-02-13 00:00:00.000000000"

how to convert it correctly?
is it possible to take out the first part of the date and convert it?

I try this
`PARSE_DATETIME('%m/%d/%Y',date)  PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y',date) PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S%Ez"`

and many more tries...

Failed to parse input string "2023-02-13 00:00:00.000000000"

Comment: would you try  `PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%F %H:%M:%E*S","2023-02-13 00:00:00.000000000")` ?

Comment: No, it doesn't help. I get the error "Failed to parse input string "date" I need to use the column name "date" and when using it I get an error. I change the date manually after unloading

Comment: Your error is saying that your actual data has another string in it rather than timestamp string. check your data first and do proper error handling if so.